# React-final-form Trigger validation on some form fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-final-form, final-form

I want to validate specific fields on some action.

I have a form with multiple fields and inside form, there is a section containing 4 fields and a separate button like `Test connection`. So, on pressing that button I want to send an API call but before that, I want to show validation errors on those specific fields. I could not find a way to do that. If you guys know, let me know. Thanks in advance.

```js
<Form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        initialValues={initData}
        render={({
          handleSubmit,
          form,
          submitting,
          pristine,
          values,
        }) => {
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form-body">
                <h2>New Data Source</h2>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="name" sm={3}>
                    Name
                  </Label>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                    <Field
                      name="name"
                      placeholder="Name"
                      innerRef={dataSourceNameRef}
                      aria-label="name"
                      component={FormInput}
                      validate={composeValidators(isRequired)}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
        
                <div className="grey">
                  <Row>
                    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="name">Hostname</Label>
                        <Field
                          name="hostname"
                          placeholder="Hostname"
                          aria-label="hostname"
                          component={FormInput}
                          validate={composeValidators(isRequired)}
                        />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={12} sm={5} md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="port">Port</Label>
                        <Field
                          name="port"
                          placeholder="Port"
                          aria-label="port"
                          component={FormInput}
                          validate={isRequired}
                        />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="name">Username</Label>
                        <Field
                          name="username"
                          placeholder="Username"
                          aria-label="name"
                          component={FormInput}
                          validate={isRequired}
                        />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="name">Password</Label>
                        <Field
                          name="password"
                          placeholder="Password"
                          aria-label="password"
                          type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                          component={FormInput}
                          validate={composeValidators(isRequired)}
                        />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} className="checkbox-field">
                      <Field
                        name="showPassword"
                        aria-label="show password"
                        component={FormInput}
                        type="checkbox"
                        label="Show Password"
                      />
                      <Label for="name"> Show Password</Label>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Field
                    name="testConnection"
                    validateFields={['username', 'hostname', 'password']}
                    component={() => (
                      <Button
                        color="secondary"
                        onClick={() => testConnection(values)}
                      >
                        Test Connection
                      </Button>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-footer justify-right">
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={submitting || pristine}
                  color="primary"
                >
                  Create
                </Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          );
        }}
      />
```

Comment: I would do the validation in your handleSubmit function (which you are not sharing).

Comment: `handleSubmit` will be invoked when there will be no error in form. As you can see, I want to validate only few fields when user will click on Test Connection button and not the all fields.

Comment: Did you solve this? I want to do it same way.

Answer (score -3):

Basically, you just have to run your validation and only run the API call if your validations pass. There's an example below, but it would be great if you could share your code to help others understand where you're at.

```
const handleCick = () => {
  if (invalid) {
    setInvalidPopup(true);
    return;
  }

  //fetch...
};
```